# Change index feed appearance of custom post types for twentytwelve theme? (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible and how should it be done? My custom post appears and works fine, and i can customize its permalink page but the index page stays the same. I tried making a content-[posttype].php + single-[posttype].php along with amending the get_templatepart code for the single-[posttype].php filebut it didn't have any affect on the appearance of the custom post type when viewd in the main index feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customise the Custom Post Type's archive page then you will need to also create a template called `archive-[posttype].php`, and in this, call the `content-[posttype].php` template part that you have already created.

For example if your Post Type is 'movies' then you would create `archive-movies.php` and in it call this (assuming `content-movies.php` is already present):

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'movies' ); ?>
```

An invaluable reference when working out which template files to use for what is the 'Official' WordPress Template Hierarchy page in the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I've been trying this with _S framework also with no success, would you have any suggestions for it? I made both the files you suggested and modified the get_template_part section but I still can only modify the permalink page of a post - not the appearance of the post in the main index.